# Draggable Div with a textarea in it. Drag problem

Tags: jquery, textarea, draggable

I have a div with a textarea in it. The main div is draggable and works fine, but I'm unable to drag the div while clicking on the textarea in it. Is there a way to drag the div even if I drag it from the textarea inside the div?

Here is how I make my div draggable

```
$('.speech_bubble').draggable(
{
      containment: $('#dropHere')

});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

It is becuase of the cancel option of the draggable. The default is ':input,option', that means that starting the drag from the textarea will be cancelled. Try playing with that option.

Comment: after your reply, I read http://old.nabble.com/%27cancel%27-attribute-in-draggable%28%29-call-td16115681s27240.html and see that cancel has a bug. Do you think that setting cancel:'' would work?

Comment: I think it would work, but there may be issues with using the textarea, e.g. text selection will not work. On the other hand, the bug report you linked is 3 years old, since than a lot of jQuery UI versions are out.

Comment: I will not be needing text selection, I'll try this one out and let you know. thank you

Comment: No, it isn't working. I also found: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/draggable-cancel-not-working .. Need to find a way to do this

Comment: The dragging works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bQ6Xs/4/ , but the textarea can't get the focus.

Comment: I need to be able to change the text in textarea and drag the div even if I drag it from the textarea.. so is this impossible?

Comment: @dioslaska, thanks a lot.. it works like a carm (after testing "thousands" of tips! :) [i just needed the drag operation of the parent div]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following styles:

```
div {
    padding-bottom:20px;
}

textarea {
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}
```

You can then drag the `textarea` while you drag on the bottom side of the `div` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a screen (Invisible div) over the textarea using the onmouseover event, then detect if the user wants to edit the text by removing the screen via double click event.

Comment: why would I do something like this? not a good idea, wouldn't prefer it as a user.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I thought it would be better to answer the exact question I had just been working on (i.e. instead of creating a new one). The answer refers to dioslaska's solution of clearing the cancel attribute with adding one additional .focus() call on the intended textarea inside your event handler (say a click). I used a double click in my solution to differentiate from simply moving my object.

For selection:

Currently it looks like there is a bug (http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4986). For a workaround, in the event handler disable the draggable by using destroy, and in the blur() (or other disabling event handler) function recreate the draggable.

Comment: You are referencing an _invalid_ bug... It's not confirmed and therefore technically speaking not a bug..